# Effects of C Rating on Battery Life

Tags: batteries, current, lithium-ion, discharge, lifetime

A polymer lithium ion battery is rated at 3.7v, 6600mAh and a maximum discharge current is specified at 3.3A. I take it this means the battery can be discharged at 3.3A and last for two hours since 6.6Ah/3.3A = 2 hours.

However, in addition to the above specifications, the battery has a nominal capacity of 6600mAh at 0.2C discharge. How does this extra bit of information affect my above calculation? I.e. How will it affect the battery life for a given current draw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the extra bit of information means is that to realize the full 6600mAh capacity of the battery you would have to limit the discharge rate to 1320mA. That gives a typical usage time of 5 hours at that load.

When you increase the discharge rate you will change several things.

- Battery cell temperature
- Total realized capacity
- Overall lifetime of the battery

Comment: A 0.2C discharge is a standardized condition for capacity estimation tests (see for example the IEC 61960-3).